# Determine rule type in string and parse arguments

Tags: c#

I have a String containing a filter rule:

```
String rule = "%john"
```

The available rules types are:

```
Equal = "value"
StartsWith = "value%"
EndsWith = "%value" 
In = "in(value1,value2,value3)"  
Range = [min;Max]  
Min = [min;]  
Max = [;Max]
```

Negation: one of the previous with ! before. 
            for example: "![min,Max]"

Given one of this rules how can determine the rule type (equal, range, etc) and get the parameters of that rule (value, min, Max, etc)?

Should I use Regex? I am not very familiar with Regex.

Comment: Can rules be *combined* with *and*, *or*? E.g. `"value | [min;max]"`?

Comment: What if I want to *equal* but with *weird* value? E.g. I want to equal to `"[123;]"` (not range!). Do you have an *escape symbol* or something?

Comment: It seems you can easily determine the rule from string (e.g. if `rule.StartWith("%")` then it's StartWith rule). So what have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: rules cannot be combined. They are already isolated.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I didn't thing about equal "[123;]" but I do not think I will have cases like that. What would you suggest?

Comment: @Sinatr: yes, I tried StartWith, EndWith and got the rest of the string with SubString. I also tried negate by determining if the first char is !. But there are rules where I am not able to use that. So I think maybe using a common approach as Regex to parse the rules might be better? Any flaws in my rules let me know ...

Comment: *"But there are rules where I am not able to use that"* - it looks like you have *specific* problem here. Can you post your attempted solution and what doesn't work (for which rule string your code doesn't work)?

Comment: @Miguel Moura: in the simpliest case (no weird input, escape characters etc.) regular expressions alone will do; however in case of doubt, please, first think over the grammar and then, probably, implement a *parser* (tokenization + syntax analysis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the simpliest case (no *escape symbols*), no *wierd cases* (e.g. when `[1;2]` should be treated as "equals to string '[1;2]'") you can well use *regular expressions* alone:

```
  // Please notice the order! E.g. check for Equals last
  List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> rules = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() {
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("Max", @"^(?<Negation>!*)\[;(?<Value>.+?)\]$"),
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("Min", @"^(?<Negation>!*)\[(?<Value>.+?);\]$"),
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("Range", @"^(?<Negation>!*)\[(?<Value>.+?;.+?)\]$"),
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("In", @"^(?<Negation>!*)in\((?<Value>.+?(,.+?)*)\)$"),
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("StartsWith", @"^(?<Negation>!*)%(?<Value>.+?)$"),
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("EndsWith", @"^(?<Negation>!*)(?<Value>.+?)%$"),
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("Equals", @"^(?<Negation>!*)(?<Value>.+?)$"),
  };

  String filter = "!!in(abc,def,xy,pq)"; // double negations cancel each other

  foreach (var rule in rules) {
    Match match = Regex.Match(filter, rule.Value);

    if (match.Success) {
      String report = String.Format("RULE: \"{0}\"; Negation: \"{1}\"; Value: \"{2}\"",
        rule.Key,
        match.Groups["Negation"].Value.Length % 2 != 0,
        match.Groups["Value"].Value);

      Console.Write(report);

      break;
    }
  }
```

The output is

> RULE: "In"; Negation: "False"; Value: "abc,def,xy,pq"

In order to get all four values *separated* use `Split`:

```
// ["abc", "def", "xy", "pq"]
String[] parts = match.Groups["Value"].Value.Split(',');
```

However if there's a possibility of *escape symbols* etc. I suggest implementing a *parser*

**Edit:** usually, we start from *grammar*, e.g. we may come to

```
  Types - int    (e.g. 123)      
          float  (e.g. -1.23e-54)
          string (e.g. abc, "123", ab%c, ab_c, ab\%c, ab\_c, 100\%, ab\"c, ab\\c, "in")
```

please, notice, that I've added `_` to `%`; in order to distinguish string from integer/float I've introduced `"` (e.g. `100` is integer and `"100"` is string). Finally, I've added \ as an escape character (e.g. if you want to find out for single quotation you can put `\"` or `"\""`)

```
  Key words =        in
  Special symbols =  [ ] ( ) , ; % _
```

operations

```
  equals   (including wild cards)
  in       (including wild cards)
  range    (min, max, range) 
  negation (the only boolean operation)
```

then you can implement *multi stage parser*:

- Tokenizer
- Parser
- Validator
- Builder

E.g. for

```
  !!in (12%3, ab\%c, pq_x%)
```

we can have

```
  Tokenization: "!", "!", "in", "(", "12%3", "ab\%c", "pq_x%", ")"
  Parsing:      "negation", 
                "negation", 
                 "in" (with three arguments: "12%3", "ab\%c", "pq_x%")
  Validating:   syntax is valid 
  Builder:      My_Field like '12%3' or 
                My_Field like '12\%3' escape '\' or
                My_Field like 'pq_x%'
```

Comment: can you clarify about "I suggest implementing a parser"? What do you mean? Isn't using Regex a way of parsing?